# How do I specify read access for known paths but disable enumeration in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'd like to specify rules in Firebase such that a path can only be accessed if it's known.

```
/root
  /messages
    /message1
    /message2
    /message3
```

If you access /messages you can receive a permission denied (or nothing).

If you explicitly access /messages/message2 you get the contents.

Update 1: Expected behaviour (iOS)

FIRDatabase
  .database()
  .reference()
  .child("invitations")
  .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

// snapshot returns nothing or permission denied.
})

```
FIRDatabase
  .database()
  .reference()
  .child("invitations/message1")
  .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

  // snapshot returns message1
})
```

Comment: See ["rules are not filters"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, but I believe the OP is asking how to prevent enumeration of the nodes under a given node, while allowing anonymous access if the user knows the DIRECT path of a given node.

I too, have been trying to figure out how to do this. Basically, I'm trying to post semi-sensitive data under a given node, while making the name of the node available securely through a different means. However, I don't want to implement a "security/user" model within Firebase. I'd simply like to use Firebase similar to an Amazon S3 bucket, where if you know the location of a key, you can download the file/data stored at that location, while still preventing enumeration/listing of the nodes within the database.

An example of such usage would be if you generate the keyname using a crypto digest such as SHA2. The key couldn't be easily generated, yet if you knew the key, you could access the node directly. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I figured out how to do this in Firebase. The solution is rather simple. Here is an example of the JSON security rules in Firebase:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users" : {
          ".read": false,
          ".write": false,
          "$child" : {
            ".read" : true,
            ".write" : true
          }
        },
        "chats" : {
          ".read" : false,
          ".write" : false,
          "$child" : {
            ".read" : true,
            ".write" : true,
          },
        },
        "comments" : {
          ".read" : false,
          ".write" : false,
          "$child" : {
            ".read" : true,
            ".write" : true
          },
        },
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

In this example, any node under "users", "chats", and "comments" is directly accessible, but enumeration is no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify the access inside the message id level.

If you were clear on what you are trying to achieve it will look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      //if you add the read permission here it will give you access to all messages
      "$message": {
        //here it will give only to the specific $message.
        //if you want to specify the exctly message id you can do something like "$message == 'message1'" on the ".read"
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".read": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it for any message given that the collection of messages will grow arbitrarily.

Comment: @trustyfrog Any message given where? Could u be more descriptive on what u are trying?

Comment: Teh collection of messages in the example will grow over time. I don;t want to specify a rule for each message. I would rather have a pattern of rules that says each message (under messages) can be read. I would like to be able to give a message ID to a user such that they can read this, but to keep the message generally hidden to those who do no know the ID explicitly.

Comment: @trustyfrog If you leave the rules the way i wrote (`".read": "auth != null"`) only authenticated users who knows the messageId (`$message`) will be able to access it.

Comment: I just tried this. If my reference is to /messages and I observe an event type this always returns the full list of messages.

Comment: @trustyfrog let me see what are you trying. show me code.